# combined primary key search in DataTable

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable, dataview

I am new to C#.net.I want a simple solution for my problem.
I have a datatable with three fields used as a PRIMARY KEY**(ITEM_CODE,WAREHOUSE_CODE,LOTNO)**.
I want to get the row index of the row that I 'm trying to match with this PRIMARY KEY from my datatable.
How can I do this?
Thanks a lot for your help and interest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem with this code,

```
int rowIndex = dt.Rows.IndexOf(dt.Select("ITEM_CODE = 'i001' AND WAREHOUSE_CODE='001' AND LOTNO='111'")[0]);
```

Thank you for all of your interest and answers.

Comment: If what you posted solved your problem please accept it as the answer.

Comment: yes,when I accepted it,"You can accept your own answer in 21 hours"Box was showned.So,I will accept as the answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `Find()` method to get the reference of `DataRow` object based upon the given values and if it is (DataRow object) not null then `compare` its reference to each row of Rows collection of Datatable and obtain the row index.